# vim, map character everywhere

Tags: key-bindings

In some keyboard, `<` and `>` are painful to hit. This is why I've remapped these 2 characters respectively to `aa` and `pp`

```
inoremap aa <
cnoremap aa <
inoremap pp >
cnoremap pp >
onoremap aa <
onoremap pp >
```

The problem is this binding doesn't work in the operator pending mode. Consider this example where _ is my cursor:

```
<tag> _foobar </tag>
```

I want my cursor to go to the `<`, so I hit `faa` but vim understands my command as : `fa` + `a` (go to the next `a`, and append).

How could I change this behavior ?

Second question : I want it to be very fast, for example, if I type `fa`, I don't want vim to wait for a second `a`. So I've set a timeout:

```
set ttimeout
set ttimeoutlen=10 "ms
```

These commands don't seem working, because if I press `a` in insert mode and another `a` 500 ms after (no chrono), a `<` appear.

Thank you for reading

Comment: For the second question, I answered myself ```set ttimeout
set timeoutlen=150 ttimeoutlen=100```

Comment: `:h f` also helps

Comment: IMHO, if you want a global remapping of `<` and `>`, you should do this at the OS level, not inside Vim. On Linux, this could be done with `xmodmap` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the purpose of the `:onoremap` mappings ?

If you want to operate on tags without typing `<` or `>`, `it` and `at` can help you.

Here are two usage examples:

- `cit` = cut the text inside the tags (**c**hange **i**nside **t**ags)
- `yat` = copy the tags and the text between them (**y**ank **a**round
  **t**ags)

If for some reasons, you can't or don't want to use the `it` and `at` objects and prefer `aa` and `pp` instead, here's a way to do it:

```
:vnoremap aa :<c-u>normal! T>vt<<cr>
:omap aa :<c-u>normal vaa<cr>

:vnoremap pp :<c-u>normal! F<v2f><cr>
:omap pp :<c-u>normal vpp<cr>
```

For the mappings in other modes (insert mode, command-line mode, argument of the `f` command), there may be other ways, but you could try adding the following code:

```
:lnoremap aa <
:lnoremap pp >
```

If I understood the help correctly, when you're in insert mode or command-line mode you will have to hit `<C-^>` to enable / disable those mappings (it will change the value of the `'iminsert'` option):

```
In Insert mode and in Command-line mode the mappings can be disabled with
the CTRL-^ command i_CTRL-^ c_CTRL-^. These commands change the value of
the 'iminsert' option.  When starting to enter a normal command line (not a
search pattern) the mappings are disabled until a CTRL-^ is typed.  The state
last used is remembered for Insert mode and Search patterns separately.  The
state for Insert mode is also used when typing a character as an argument to
command like "f" or "t".
```

For more information, see:

```
:help language-mapping
:help 'iminsert'
:help i_CTRL-^
:help c_CTRL-^
:help v_it
:help v_at
```